# What does performance speed refers to? Aircraft performance in general

Tags: aircraft-performance

For example C172R specifications:
Cruise speed:122 knots
What does this mean? 
Maximum achievable Indicated airspeed At specific conditions? 
Another example - rate of climb: 721 ft/min 
For what conditions? So much factors can affect this..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the POH - it will show the conditions the speed was measured under.

> Cruise, 75% Power at 8500 Feet. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 122 KNOTS
>
> **NOTE**
>
> *Speed performance is shown for an airplane equipped with
>   speed fairings which increase the speeds by
>   approximately 2 knots. There is a corresponding difference
>   in range, while all other performance figures are
>   unchanged when speed fairings are installed.
>
> The above performance figures are based on airplane weights at 2450
>   pounds, standard atmospheric conditions, level, hard-surfaced dry
>   runways and no wind. They are calculated values derived from flight
>   tests conducted by Cessna Aircraft Company under carefully
>   documented conditions and will vary with individual airplanes and
>   numerous factors affecting flight performance.

(http://www.airilm.com/wp-content/uploads/172R-POH.pdf)

Comment: 122 Indicated or true ?